# How to use Keras ImageDataGenerator while reading ground truth from CSV file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to load [*ISIC 2019* dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/andrewmvd/isic-2019) using Keras (version: 2.5.0) to later be fed to a CNN model. Basically, I would use `keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()` and `flow_from_directory()` to load and augment my image dataset. Here's an example:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(path_to_training_subdir,
                                              target_size=(224, 224),
                                              batch_size=20,
                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                              subset='training')
```

Everything works fine as long as the directory of my dataset is structured like this:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......a_image_1.jpg
......a_image_2.jpg
...class_b/
......b_image_1.jpg
......b_image_2.jpg
```

However, some datasets (such as ISIC 2019) take another approach: putting all images in a single directory and attaching a CSV file which contains the title of each image and its corresponding label. In this case:

```
image,MEL,NV,BCC,AK,BKL,DF,VASC,SCC,UNK
ISIC_0000000,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
ISIC_0000001,0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
...
```

Since I'm new to Keras, I have no idea how to use `ImageDataGenerator()` in such situation. The only way I can think of is writing some sort of script to distribute all samples among multiple subdirectories corresponding to class labels and actually building the desired directory structure before passing it to `flow_from_directory()`, but I know no efficient way to do that either.

I was wondering if Keras itself features a specific function for this matter, or if there's any library to help restructuring the dataset based on a CSV file to be compatible with Keras.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another function [`flow_from_dataframe()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) with the same functionality as `flow_from_directory()` which provides for you reading from CSV instead from a structured directory.

Here is an example:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("ISIC.csv")
# merge all classes into one column 
df["labels"] = df[["MEL","NV","BCC","AK","BKL","DF","VASC","SCC","UNK"]].values.tolist()
# if your image names have no extension
df['image'] = df['image'].astype(str) + '.jpg' 

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(df,
                                              directory="./isic_images",
                                              x_col="image",
                                              y_col="labels",
                                              target_size=(224, 224),
                                              batch_size=32,
                                              class_mode='categorical',
                                              )
```

Comment: That worked almost like magic. Thank you, sir! There was an issue, however: the CSV file is one-hot encoded. But the provided example assigns the samples into two classes of 0.0's and 1.0's rather than the nonuple classes. Therefore, I came up with one-hot "decoding" the `df["labels"]` to make it be compatible with `class_mode='categorical'`. I doubt my solution, though, to be a practical one. Would you recommend any editing?

Comment: I gathered all 9 classes into 1 new column, named labels. This column holds one-hot encoded of nonuple classes info. You can see sample data by `df.head()` . e.g. 1 samples is associated with [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], which means I assigned it to the first class, MEL. It is already one-hot encoded.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you should create a Data Generator. Refer to the example here

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence

What you need is a class that inherits tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence. Then implement the **len** and **getitem** methods. You can then use this object of this class as generator in the model.fit and model.evaluate functions.